# Calling tableView.deleteRows([indexPath], with: .automatic) is removing the cell but without animation. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: swift, uitableview, animation

Below is the code I call from a delegate closure implemented by the tableview in question.

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.tableView.beginUpdates()
      self.viewModel.sensorIdsByFilteredAssetsArr.value[indexPath.section].remove(at: indexPath.row)
      
      self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
      
      
      self.tableView.endUpdates()
 }
```

Comment: Try `with: .fade`

Comment: None of the animation options work. They all result in the cell just disappearing with no animation.

Comment: Maybe you call somewhere `tableView.reloadData()` ?